# Integration of fractional function over Rice distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, integration, special-functions

Let $a>2$ be a real variable. My objective is to find an approximation of the integral  defined as
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty } {\frac{1}{{1 + {x^a}}}} f\left( {x|y} \right)\, dx
\end{equation}
Here $a$ is positive real number and $f\left( {x|y} \right)$ is the Rice distribution
$$
f\left( {x|y} \right) := \frac{x}{{{\sigma ^2}}}{e^{\left( { - \frac{{{x^2} + {y^2}}}{{{\sigma ^2}}}} \right)}}{I_0}\left( {\frac{{xy}}{{{\sigma ^2}}}} \right),
$$
where ${I_0}$ is the modiﬁed Bessel function with order zero.

Comment: I think you meant $a$ is a positive number. Are you looking for an asymptotic approximation or one for numerical work?

Comment: Also, might want to tack on a $dx$ to your integral.